# Conditional Probability Definition

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is how my text defines conditional probability:

[image]

I understand why they say that $\sum_{\omega \in B} \Pr[\omega] = \Pr[B]$ is less than $1$ because the entire sample space $\Omega$ contains samples that are not in $B$. I think I also understand that we want to scale the probability of each sample point by $\frac{1}{\Pr[B]}$ because we want the sum of all $\omega \in B$ to equal $1$. I think they want them to equal $1$ because $B$ should be "guaranteed" to happen when all of its $\omega \in B$ are added up.

However, I don't understand the notation $\Pr[\omega \mid B] = \frac{\Pr[\omega]}{\Pr[B]}$. I know that in English it reads "The probability of $\omega$ given $B$ equals the probability of $\omega$ scaled by the probability of $B$" but I'm still a little unconvinced that my intuition stated above is correct.

Comment: Note that in the text it says that the singleton $\omega \in B$. If you are aware of this then the statements you say above is ok. Not sure what intuition you want to convince yourself..

Comment: Which part of the text says that? Don't know where I went wrong

Comment: The series bounds.  $\sum\limits_{\omega\in B} \ldots~,~ \sum\limits_{\omega\in A\cap B}\ldots$

Comment: In the text before the equation, it reminds that "for each sample point $\omega \in B$, the new probability becomes" and then the equation you stated. So I mean you just need to aware that this particular equation is applicable only to those $\omega \in B$, or more generally those sets which is a subset of $B$. Everything you state here looks fine, so not sure what is the unconvincing part.

Comment: Great thanks, guess I just needed a sanity check then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally $\omega$ denotes an outcome in the sample space of $\Omega$.

The events $A,B$ are each subsets of the sample space; that is, events are sets of outcomes.

$\Pr$ is a probability measure of an event.   $\Pr(\omega)$, a.k.a. $\Pr(\{\omega\})$, is the measure for a single outcome.   (We usually leave off the set braces for reasons of laziness).

So $\Pr(\omega\mid B)$ is the conditional measure of that outcome when given the event $B$.

Strictly speaking, $\Pr(\omega\mid B) = \Pr(\{\omega\}\cap B) \div \Pr(B)$ but *when* we are assured that $\omega\in B$ *then* that is $\Pr(\omega)\div\Pr(B)$.   This assurance is provided by the series bounds.

So $$\Pr(A\mid B)~=~\sum_{\omega\in A}\Pr(\omega\mid B)~=~\dfrac{\sum\limits_{\omega\in (A\cap B)}\Pr(\omega) + \sum\limits_{\omega\in A\setminus B} 0}{\Pr(B)}~=~\dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$$

---

**tl;dr** Your intition is essentially correct.